# Can a variable be used in docker FROM?

Tags: docker

I am wondering if a env variable can be used in a docker from? Reason for this is to control the tagging. For example, say I have this line in my Dockerfile:

```
FROM myApp
```

What I want is this:

```
FROM myApp:${VERSION}
```

This way I can say `docker build . myApp --build-arg VERSION=9`

The process to build docker images for this app is the same. I don't want to have Dockerfiles that are almost identical just to use a different base image.If I want to build version 9, it should use version 9 of the base image.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Quoting [this link](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/18119#issuecomment-321728032)
:

> This is now possible if anyone comes here looking for answers: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact

`FROM` instructions support variables that are declared by any `ARG` instructions that occur before the first `FROM`.

```
ARG  CODE_VERSION=latest
FROM base:${CODE_VERSION}
CMD  /code/run-app

FROM extras:${CODE_VERSION}
CMD  /code/run-extras
```

Answer (score 37):

For at least this docker version this is feasible

```
docker --version
docker version 18.09.8, build bfed4f5
```

It requires a preset variable in Dockerfile  e.g.

```
ARG TAG=latest
FROM traefik:${TAG}
```

Then you can override this preset with the following

```
docker build --build-arg "TAG=2.2.8" -t my-app:$TAG
```

The version number will not show up during build. if you want to test if it works, reference a non-existing version - it will fail with: manifest my-app:version not found.

Comment: did you miss a Double quotes

Comment: FWIW, this also works in 18.06.3.

Comment: `docker build --build-arg "TAG=2.2.8" -t my-app:$TAG
` will throw error : `invalid argument "my-app:" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format`

Comment: did you define TAG before  (e.g. export TAG=2.2.8   in bash)

Answer (score 3):

You could simply generate your Dockerfile from a template.  Put
something like this in a Makefile:

```
MYTAG=latest

.PHONY: Dockerfile
Dockerfile: Dockerfile.in
    sed 's/MYTAG/$(MYTAG)/' $< > $@ || rm -f $@
```

Then you can run:

```
make MYTAG=8; docker build -t my-app-8 .
```

This would only make sense if you are frequently building images that
require a different tag in the `FROM` line.

Comment: I thought about that. I was just hoping for a native docker feature for this.

Comment: There's no native solution; there is an open proposal/feature request though; https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18119

Answer (score 1):

Build your container programatically using [buildah](https://github.com/projectatomic/buildah) (It can take Dockerfile too).

So for your use-case:

```
 VERSION=v0.1.0

 myCon=$(buildah from myApp:${VERSION})

 buildah config --cmd "sleep 1d" $myCon

 buildah commit $myCon $USER/sleeping1d
```

You can obviously script it, save and invoke it, and one more advantage is
[buildah](https://github.com/projectatomic/buildah) doesn't need docker daemon running, which is great for CI. Also it's an open-source project, check out the project page.

BTW I saw this issue lately which is exactly what you want - https://github.com/projectatomic/buildah/issues/581

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately it's not possible to do that. The first line of your Dockerfile *must* be a `FROM` directive, and so that precludes the use of the `ARG` directive. There is a good answer there from larsks about generating a Dockerfile, but I'd also like to suggest merely creating different Dockerfiles and then specifying a particular one in your `docker build` command using the `-f` switch:

```
docker build -t codemiester/app:latest -f ./Dockerfile.apache2.ubuntu
```

Comment: I can do that. It is just a pain, given as I mentioned the process is the same regardless of versions. And I also, want an easy mechanism to keep image and base image synchronized.