# Docker image build fails to recognize build argument : invalid reference format

Tags: docker, build, dockerfile, arguments

I'm building a docker file and the it fails at the first line.

```
FROM artifactory.company.com/local-docker-repo/dockerimage/docker-batch-base:$VERSION
```

I pass the build arguments this way

```
docker image build --build-arg VERSION=latest -q -t artifactory.company.com/local-docker-repo/batch/batch-run-sst:1.0-SNAPSHOT .
```

But it throws an error saying invalid reference format

```
Step 1/5 : FROM artifactory.company.com/local-docker-repo/dockerimage/docker-batch-base:$VERSION
invalid reference format
```

What am I missing here

Comment: Have you declared a `ARG VERSION`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a variable be used in docker FROM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36556766/can-a-variable-be-used-in-docker-from)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to declare ARG VERSION in the docker file before using it. Thanks @Ali Tou